# How to extract values from json response of Google's distance API and store in python dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to python and am struggling with how to insert the values I'm extracting from Google's distance API json return to a dataframe.

For example, this is the json response:

```
    {'destination_addresses': ['Victoria, BC, Canada'],
 'origin_addresses': ['Vancouver, BC, Canada'],
 'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '114 km', 'value': 114210},
     'duration': {'text': '3 hours 1 min', 'value': 10862},
     'status': 'OK'}]}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

I have figured out how to extract the values and print them. But I would like to store them in a dataframe.  I created a loop to get the four values I need:

```
level0 = ["distance","duration"]
level1 = ["value", "text"]

for level in level0:
    for item in level1:
        print (result["rows"][0]["elements"][0][level][item])
```

Essentially I need to end up with a dataframe with the origin, destination, and the 4 combinations of elements I list above. I'm not sure how to insert those values into a dataframe the way I have this set up.  Did I just set up my loop incorrectly?

I was able to put the values into a list but then I'm not sure what to do from there to get the values into a row.

Ultimately I will be looping through many combinations of origins and destinations so I will have many rows, one for each test.

TIA!

Comment: If you create a list of dicts, then you can use ```df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)```.

Comment: Interesting. I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a list of dictionaries as Eric pointed out in the comments worked!